Image preview for any file (C#, WinForms)
I'm developing a winform with C# and provided any file's path I'd like to show a preview of the file, perhaps in a PictureBox. I found this
How to get thumbnails from a file
and tried to check for what's in there but I stopped because I saw I need to import some Windows.Storage.FileProperties or something to use the StorageItemThumbnail class. My problem is there seems to be no such element to import in the code. So I ask, could you help me to import that class? Or, if you happen to know, suggest some other easy method to create preview images. My idea would be like, if it's some file you get a real preview of, it creates an image of that, otherwise the preview is just the icon. I don't actually know which files aside images can get a real preview and as such I would start from there, with pictures. That said, I accept suggestions about it.
I'm getting the files names from selecting TreeView nodes, just to be more specific.

They are Windows Runtime (WinRT) classes. Read Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps
